# How relevant or outdated is the Mootorial at this point?

Tags: mootools, javascript

I'm looking to learn MooTools, and the [Mootorial](http://mootorial.com/wiki/) seems like the most complete, comprehensive place to start.  But it says that it's designed very specifically for MT v. 1.2 and it seems that we're now on like 1.4.5.  So, I'm wondering, will learning from that MooTorial be doing myself a disservice, or is it worth it?

Alternatively, feel free to answer the question *What is the single best tutorial to learn mootools from scratch for someone coming from a sort of shallow jquery background?*

---

As a side note, is the nettutsplus premium tutorial any good if anyone's tried it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mootorial is still pretty relevant. api changes have not been that significant since the 1.2.5 days. of note are: event delegation is now a part of core. all methods that had $ in the name have been deprecated. the rest is pretty much the same... some best practices may have shifted but for a new starter, it is more than adequate, see the full list of breaking changes here: https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/wiki/Update-from-1.2-to-1.3

if you are familiar with js, I very much recommend reading a book written by Mark Obcena - Pro Javascript with MooTools, look it up on Amazon. It is probably not for an absolute beginner but it is written extremely well and explains what happens under the hood.

Comment: So, then... the `$$` dom selector engine has been removed...?! I know basic programming concepts and I can crank out some very basic javascript.  I can get simple things done, but not much more beyond that.  I don't know much about prototypal inheritance yet, or much else about the advanced inner workings of JS though I'm trying to learn.  Aside from stuff moving to different modules (which I bet I'll figure out quite quickly) the usage of it all is still the same?  What would you recommend given my programming level... the mootorial or the book to start off with?  Thanks.

Comment: Also, are there any other comprehensive-ish, ground-up beginners' mootools tutorials that you could recommend floating around on the web?

Comment: PS, how is the net tuts plus tutorial...? Do you have any experience with that? Thanks.

Comment: well $$ and $ are still in but they alias other methods. el.getElements an document.id. not sure of net tuts one post it and I will review it. we really ought to write new ones and we will once the new website launches

Comment: +1 on Mark's Pro Javascript with Mootools, great read.

Comment: Any **E**TA on the new site, however rough, or vague?  Thanks.  It seems like having a free, accurate, quality ebook-tutorial should be a high priority for something like mootools, because it's really the way to grow the community.  For someone in my position trying to choose a library to learn, not having a clear answer and having to make a post like this really tips the scale against MT.  And if I do go with MT, which I will, so don't worry (:P), I could easily see myself contributing more documentation and what not later on.  At the end of the day, there's no way to grow the community and..

Comment: popularize the library without having a nice warm fuzzy groundup tutorial available for abs. beginners, the point from which everyone starts.  With this situation, more and more people will fall into the spaghetti code easy-and-fun-but-messy-as-hell trap of jquery.  Just my two cents.  The moral of the story is I'm curious how far off we are from a new site and updated tut. :)  The net tuts tutorial is behind a paywall, so if nobody's seen it before and able to comment i probably won't pay to see it :-/

Comment: I hear you and yet I cannot comment on an ETA. There will be some work on that done at a hackathlon at the end of the month but I am not sure if it will be enough as it's not the only focus. Several people, myself included, have volunteered their spare time to write content after the site and the new forge and new docs are done. oh yes. the new docs will have a LOT more. inline code, comments etc, so that ought to help as well. I will also have a look at what will be involved in updating the mootorial, it's a repo you can clone and work on. the biggest drawback is time & mootools 2 being done